# Sails.js waterline defered

Tags: mongodb, sails.js

I am newbie in sails.js and MongoDB. Thanks for read my question.

I got really trouble.

---

**Situation**

I have User db, Report db, Post db.

I want to get Report data and populated post data which parent is Report data. And I also want to get User data from post data.

In other words, I want to get double nested data.

```
Report
  |_ post
      |_user
```

And this is my findReports action in ReportController.js

```
findReports: function(req, res) {
    Report.find().populateAll().sort({createdAt: -1}).exec((er, reports) => {
      if (er) return res.negotiate(er)
      const rs = reports
      console.log('rs : ', rs)
      rs.forEach((report) => {
        if(report.post) {
          User.findOne({id: report.post.user}).exec((er, user) => {
            report.post.user = user
            console.log("before rs : ", rs)
          })
          console.log("report.post.user : ", report.post.user)
          console.log("after rs : ", rs)
        } else {
          report.comment.user = User.findOne({id: report.comment.user}).exec((er, user) => {
            report.commet.user = user
          })
        }
      })
      console.log("final rs : ", rs)
      res.view('dashboard/reports/index', { reports: rs })
    })
  },
```

When I run my code, In my console, result is printed according following order.

1. "after rs : ..(blah).." - I don't want...
2. "final rs : ..(blah).." - I don't want...
3. "before rs : ..(blah).." - I want to get this rs! but when my res.view("dashboard....", {reports, rs}) is 2's result.

I think when "User.find" method is defered unrelevant to whole logic.

I really get in trouble. Any advice will be really helpful. Please, give me some advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Waterline form SailsJS doesn't support deepPopulation. So instead of the ORM you must use another like: [Offshore](https://github.com/atiertant/offshore)

Example:

```
Report.find().populate("post.user").exec((err, data) => {
 // ur code here
})
```